# $(window).scroll not working

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to load the content when scrolling down on the page. I am calling my method this way:

```
$(function() {
    fadeBlocksIn();

    $(window).scroll(function() {
        fadeBlocksIn();
        console.log("scrolled");
    });
});
```

The first `fadeBlocksIn` calling seems like successful, because some of the elements (visible on the screen without scrolling down) appears, but when i am scrolling down, nothing happens.

The function itself:

```
function fadeBlocksIn() {
    $('.custom-invisible').each(function (i) {

        var top_of_object = $(this).position().top;
        var bottom_of_window = $(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height();

        bottom_of_window = bottom_of_window - 50;

        if (top_of_object < bottom_of_window) {
            $(this).animate({ 'opacity': '1' }, 500);
        }
    });
}
```

I put a `console-log` after the function call to check wether the method calls successful or not, and as i do not get anything in the console log, i assume it isn't successful.

Any idea how to change the script to fadein all the hidden elements when scrolling down?

Comment: use jquery fadeOut on your class at initialization function and fadeIn(500) on desired event.

Comment: something is wrong with my css, when i take it down, everything is working just fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is the correct syntax for animating opacity:

```
$(this).animate({opacity: 1}, 500);
```

also consider initially hiding your class using css("opacity",0) not visibility:hidden.